# How would I click a uialertcontroller action to enter/edit text into a uialertcontroller textfield? Swift 3, Xcode 8, IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

Basically, [i have an alert controller set up so that when i click a button in the view controller, an alert controller pops up and i can type words into a textfield, click an "OK" button](https://ashfurrow.com/img/import/blog/uialertviewcontroller-example/9EA0E4E86AB54891A9A27BC24D1C8889.png) and it inserts that text into a label in the view controller. Ive extended this ability so that i can have [preset keywords (like "Good," "Likely" and "Almost") that i can select from in the alert controller to speed up the typing process, as these words are typed a lot in my app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHrJt.png) I was wondering if you could also edit those key words that I've selected? So instead of clicking my preset word and it just being sent to my label, can i send it to my textfield, edit it, and then send it to my label with the OK button?

```
//Editable Text Box with Preset Keywords

@IBOutlet weak var UselessLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func UselessTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Useless Button Tapped")
    openUselessAlert()

}

func openUselessAlert() {

    //Create Alert Controller
    let alert9 = UIAlertController (title: "Uselss:", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Good", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Good"}

    alert9.addAction(bt1)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Likely", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Likely"}

    alert9.addAction(bt2)

    //preset keyword as button in alert controller
    let bt3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Almost", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (action) in self.UselessLabel.text = "Almost"}

    alert9.addAction(bt3)

    //Create Cancel Action
    let cancel9 = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

    alert9.addAction(cancel9)


    //Create OK Action
    let ok9 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in print("OK")
        let textfield = alert9.textFields?[0]
        print(textfield?.text!)
        self.UselessLabel.text = textfield?.text!
    }

    alert9.addAction(ok9)

    //Add Text Field
    alert9.addTextField { (textfield: UITextField) in
        textfield.placeholder = "Useless"
    }

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.present(alert9, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Please help! Im really new to Xcode and programming in general, so I'm a huge idiot when it comes to this.

Thanks :)

Comment: I am a bit unclear of what you want to do, e.g. If I click "Good" button the textfield will contains "Good"?

Comment: Yes, exactly!  - that way i can edit the text after i have selected a preset word

Comment: It's not possible, as `UIAlertController` will disappear as soon as you press any button (so I've deleted my answer). You have two options here: present new `UIAlertController` with the filled `message`, or you'll have to implement custom view controller with the same functionality.

Comment: how would I code your first option? Sorry, I'm really bad at this.